# Combine image with URL into one image

Tags: image-processing

I have images from the internet and the corresponding URLs.
I want to combine the image and the URL into one image.
I don't want the URL to be placed over part of the image, but want the URL under the image. I tried GraphicsColumn and it worked, but makes the URL and the image the same size. In the code below, the 1273 is the width obtained via ImageDimensions. I tried changing the height also, but then the URL is not shown fully.

[image: See this]

The image of the triangle is at https://www.pinterest.com/pin/310115124325383020/
I want the URL to have the same width but a smaller height.
Suggestions?

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img = RandomImage[1, {350, 150}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"];

Labeled[img, {"https://www.pinterest.com/pin/310115124325383020/"}, {Bottom}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest drawing the text directly onto the image using `ImageCompose` or `HighlightImage`. Example:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];

text = Text[Style["Mandrill", 20, Bold, TextAlignment -> Center]];
textImg = Rasterize@Graphics[{text}, ImageSize -> {w, 25}];

ImageCompose[
 ImagePad[img, {{0, 0}, {25, 0}}, White],
 textImg,
 {Center, Bottom},
 {Center, Bottom}
 ]
```

[image: Output]

With `HighlightImage`:

```
HighlightImage[
 ImagePad[img, {{0, 0}, {25, 0}}, White], {
  Black,
  Text[
   Style["Mandrill", 20, Bold, TextAlignment -> Center],
   {w/2, 0},
   {0, -1}
   ]
  }]
```

> Same output as above.